# PowerReadFriendlyName reports false buffer length

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, power-management, ref

I'm making a C# program that retrieves the name of a power management scheme from it's GUID by PInvoking the Win32 function [PowerReadFriendlyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372740(v=vs.85).aspx). However, the function seems to report false buffer length.

```
Guid id = new Guid("381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e"); // "Balanced" scheme GUID
uint length = 0;

IntPtr ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(id));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(id, ptr, true);

PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, ptr, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, ptr, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, ref length);
```

`PowerReadFriendlyName` is called twice. One time with a null pointer as buffer, for retrieving the required buffer length. Again with a buffer with the correct length, for actually reading the name.

After the first call, `length` is an absurdly large number, but it's always `126` for the *Balanced* scheme.

After the second call, `buffer` has been populated with the correct characters, and `length` is suddenly `20`, which sounds more correct.

Both calls return `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

**TL;DR:** According to [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372740(v=vs.85).aspx), a null reference as buffer makes the function report the required buffer length. However, when the null reference is present, an incorrect minimum length is reported. Passing an array (empty or not) makes the function report the correct minimum length.

**What causes this behaviour and how can it be prevented?**

`PowerReadFriendlyName` is declared as follows:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 PowerReadFriendlyName
(
    IntPtr RootPowerKey, 
    IntPtr SchemeGuid, 
    IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid, 
    IntPtr PowerSettingGuid, 
    Byte[] Buffer, 
    ref UInt32 BufferSize
);
```

Testing a different scheme: The *High performance* scheme makes the first call report `114`, while the second call reports `22`.

**EDIT:** It's probably worth noting that *Balanced* is localized *Balansert*, and *High performance* is *Høy ytelse* in the debug environment.

Comment: The first call should return ERROR_MORE_DATA. I'd like to see code that checks return values.

Comment: I did use a debugger to check the return values, and they are both `ERROR_SUCCESS` as stated above. According to the MSDN, the function returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` when the `Buffer` parameter is a null reference, and the `BufferLength` will be set to the required buffer length. When I used an empty buffer instead of a null reference, the reported minimum length was correct, and the function returned `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. Why does using a null reference make the function report incorrect data?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please show a complete program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [I set up a repo on GitHub](http://github.com/osvein/PowerTray). Unfortunately, I forgot to push the latest commit, and currently I do not have access to the local repository. However, code similar to the above has been commented out in *PowerTray/PowerIcon.cs*, in `PowerIcon.Refresh()`.

Comment: You can create a 20 line console app that repros this and include it in the Q. I did that in C++ for simplicity. P/invoke isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As to why returned sizes are larger than (/don't match) the exact amount needed, "Functions that return the size of a required buffer generally return upper bounds, not tight bounds" -  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20240214-00/?p=109400

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35827609)